# Replacement for the word "mediator"

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to look for a word that means: a person that organizes communication between two or more parties.

For example: If I work with a group and we must communicate with a company and a professor, and I were to make sure everyone is on the same page and communicate between the three groups, what would I be?

I can only think of *mediator*. However it seems to imply that these groups are in conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that mediator implies conflict resolution. If the person is an actual member of the group I would say they were a representative, otherwise I would say she is a go-between.

Comment: That's a great word choice! Since the person is an actual member of the group, representative fits perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

An option with a slightly more formal feel is [liaison](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liaison):

> a person who helps organizations or groups to work together and provide information to each other

I've personally seen it used more often during my time in the armed forces, but many other organizations use it as well. For loads of usage examples, fire up a job search site.

Note: There are other meanings for the word, so make sure the context is there. For instance, it can also refer to a (usually illicit) sexual encounter. It's normally immediately apparent which meaning is being used, but it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the word *middleman*.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion, however I think I will go with @GeorgeWhite's answer since the person is a member of one of the groups.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **[facilitator](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/facilitator)**

> a person or organization that helps another person or organization to do or achieve something
>
> *The conference is chaired by a highly skilled facilitator who has been fully trained.*
>
> *The teacher both participates in and acts as facilitator in the collaborative context*

Answer (score 1):

There's also *interlocutor* which google's handy new definition service defines as:

> a person who takes part in a dialogue or conversation.

Though with what you are describing, I might go with the locution *project coordinator* or *project manager*. The former if this person is not in control of much, the latter if the person can order different groups around.